# Id is not comming into REST axios in my Product component?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

After gaining some experience in back-end development, I got bored to create beautiful things and not seeing them, so i decided to move towards front-end, with concrete thoughts that it is easy=)

And here is my first problem...
Product Id is not coming into my axios REST api, so the Product can't be rendered,because back-end can't send JSON

Also when i try to hit the button that Links into my Product component, this happens

```
to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
 http://localhost:8080/product/undefined
```

Product component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

const Product = () =>{
  const [items,setItems] = useState([]);
  const {id} = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  fetchItems();
}, []); 

const fetchItems = () => {
    axios
        .get(
          `http://localhost:8080/product/${id}`
        )
        .then((res) => {
            setItems(res.data);
            console.log(res.product);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        });
};
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) =>(
          <div className='product-container' key={item.id}>
            <div>
              <img className='prod-image' src={item.imageURL} alt='' />
            </div>
            <div>
              <h2>{item.name}</h2>
              <p>{item.description}</p>
              <p>
                <strong>Price:</strong> {item.price}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Product;
```

Home component that lists all Products

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchProducts();
}, []);

const fetchProducts = () => {
  axios
    .get('http://localhost:8080/product/')
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setProducts(res.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Наша продукция</h1>
      <div className='item-container'>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <div className='card' key={product.id}>
            <img src={product.imageURL} alt='' />
            <h3>{product.name}</h3>
            <p>{product.description}</p>
            <a>{product.price} &#8381;</a>
              <Link to={`/product/${product.id}`}>View</Link>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

```
i am getting this error 
items.map is not a function
TypeError: items.map is not a function
    at Product (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1085:67)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26207:22)
    at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29089:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30801:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15799:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15843:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15900:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35774:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35021:16)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:34944:9)
```

Comment: You can do like this > const { id } = useParams();

Comment: Typo?  You forgot the parentheses to *invoke* the `useParams` function...

Comment: @sedhal mistyped, sorry. I changed code not it actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo mistake. You can use useParams as a function.

```
const {id} = useParams();
```

Comment: Changing this, i am getting new error; ```items.map is not a function```

Answer (score 1):

before fetch request item is empty or null so you need set to optional variable , It is telling the Compiler if  item exist then do mapping
see code bellow

```
items.map to items?.map
```

Comment: Still getting the same error with items.map is not a function

Comment: May it is because product comes as an object and not as an array/ and in this case i just don't need to loop over it?

Comment: check return object  console.log(typeof  item); is it array or object ?!